# Execution freezing while checking if Word is Visible

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm check to see if Word is still visible before I perform certain tasks. The problem is execution just freezes after I close Word 2010 on the check of the visibility. Does not occur with 2007.

```
//Initializing Word and Document

While(WordIsOpen())
{
}

//Perform Post Close Tasks

public bool WordIsOpen()
{
     if(MyApp.Application.Visible)//Execution just freezes at this line after Word is not visible
            return true;
     else
            return false;
}
```

Anyone see this issue before?

Is there a better way to check this?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application MyApp

Comment: Does this happen only during debugging sessions? I wonder if winword.exe is being attached-to by VS that it causes it to block on MyApp.Application.Visible. What happens if you run your project without debugging?

Comment: Office apps are apartment threaded COM apps, deadlock is always around the corner if you don't handle threading correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to declare a sentinel flag:

```
private bool isWordApplicationOpen;
```

When initializing your [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx) instance, subscribe to its [`Quit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.quit) event, and reset the flag from there:

```
MyApp = new Word.Application();
MyApp.Visible = true;
isWordApplicationOpen = true;
((ApplicationEvents3_Event)MyApp).Quit += () => { isWordApplicationOpen = false; };
// ApplicationEvents3_Event works for Word 2002 and above
```

Then, in your loop, just check whether the flag is set:

```
while (isWordApplicationOpen)
{
    // Perform work here.       
}
```

**Edit**: Given that you only need to wait until the Word application is closed, the following code might be more suitable:

```
using (ManualResetEvent wordQuitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

    try
    {
        ((Word.ApplicationEvents3_Event)app).Quit += () =>
        {
            wordQuitEvent.Set();
        };

        app.Visible = true;

        // Perform automation on Word application here.

        // Wait until the Word application is closed.
        wordQuitEvent.WaitOne();
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea what type of event args the event handle requires?

Comment: The event delegate is [`ApplicationEvents4_QuitEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_quiteventhandler.aspx), which does not take parameters and returns void.

Comment: You could handle `.Quit` with what needs to happen at application end and avoid the spinning wait altogether.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: I wasn’t implying a spinning wait; I assumed the OP wanted to perform some repeated operation within their `while` loop. Now clarified answer.

Comment: I just added the comment because it "appeared" to be a spinning wait in the question.  If possible, the event-based approach is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: In that case, definitely. I might have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: No tasks are performed in the loop. It is simply there to continually check if Word is visible and not move forward in the application until the user has closed Word.

Comment: I'm getting an error with this approach. `Cannot assign to 'Quit' because it is a 'method group'`

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: Yes, COM did have an unfortunate habit of using the same names for events and methods. Please try the updated code.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: Just read your former comment. I wouldn’t recommend you use my approach in that case.